# ValueError:Cannot render objects with any missing geometries

Tags: python, valueerror

I wrote this code in order to have a map with population in other words i wanted polygan layer  but I got an error
here is my code:

```
import folium
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv("Volcanoes.txt")

lat=list(data["LAT"])
lon=list(data["LON"])
elev=list(data["ELEV"])

def color_producer(elevation):
    if elevation < 1000:
        return 'green'
    elif 1000<=elevation<3000:
        return 'orange'
    else:
        return 'red'

map=folium.Map(location=[42.304386,-83.066254],zoom_start=6,tiles="Stamen Terrain")

fg=folium.FeatureGroup(name="My Map")


for lt, ln ,el in zip(lat,lon,elev) :

    fg.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[lt,ln],radius=6,popup=str(el)+"m",
    fill_color=color_producer(el),color='grey',fill_opacity=0.7))

fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=open('world.json','r',encoding='utf-8-sig'),style_function=lambda x:{'fillColor':'yellow' }))
map.add_child(fg)


map.save("Map1.html")
```

this is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Vida\Desktop\Webmapping_real\map1.py", line 28, in <module>
    fg.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=open('world.json','r',encoding='utf-8-sig'),style_function=lambda x:{'fillColor':'yellow' }))
  File "C:\Users\Vida\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py", line 499, in __init__
    self.data = self.process_data(data)
  File "C:\Users\Vida\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py", line 544, in process_data
    raise ValueError('Cannot render objects with any missing geometries'
ValueError: Cannot render objects with any missing geometries: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='world.json' mode='r' encoding='utf-8-sig'>
PS C:\Users\Vida\Desktop\Webmapping_real>
```

would you please help me how to fix it?